# List databases with Zend Framework

Tags: database, zend-framework, zend-db

Is it possible to list databases using Zend_Db or any other component from ZF ?

Answer (score 4):

There is not a `Zend_Db->showDatabases()` command, but you can execute the query 'SHOW DATABASES' (assuming mysql) and loop through the results.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use multiDb and want a list of all your databases hooked up in your application. Detecting databases on your server/network or ones not included in your application is nothing ZF should be used for.

For getting all your databases currently connected with multiDb you can use the following in a controller

```
$bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
$resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('multidb');

$resource instanceof Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb;
$options = $resource->getOptions();
// getOptions is a little misleading because it actually is an array with all your db configs
```

Note that the documentation for [Zend_Db_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) mentions the registry for storing additional databases which is another option and not covered with multiDb